# pybind11 in macOS 14

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I used the image of macOS 10.14.6 on VMware workstation16 pro, and tried to run the small demo in the pybind11 manual on the virtual machine, but I still have problems after trying many commands.
I used the method that can be run on both Windows and Linux: setup.py sets the path of python and pybind11, and then use the command:
python setup.py build_ext --inplace

But an error will be reported in the mac, the error screenshot is as follows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EiJ7h.png)
By the way, I can import the library Pybind11 in IDLE.
Does anyone know the reason?

Comment: Please read [why not upload images of errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and  [how do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question!

Comment: Looks like you didn't link with libpython, but your question is missing so much information...